# Zookeeper/Kafka: No Kafka brokers detected from Zookeeper cluster (Kafka runs fine)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have created a Kafka cluster with 4 nodes, a Zookeeper cluster with 3 nodes. Kafka is operating at v2.4.0 and Zookeeper at v3.5.6. Kafka cluster successfully starts and could successfully establish a connection with one of the nodes in the Zookeeper cluster (checked kafka logs), to that I can *create/list* topics, *produce/consume* messages off of this cluster when I use the `--bootstrap-server` option. But, upon using the `--zookeeper` option, things starts failing.

I also tried to list the kafka brokers using `zkCli.sh` utility that comes along with the standalone zookeeper installation, but, I got an empty list `[]`.

Command used:

```
./zkCli.sh -server localhost:2181
ls /brokers/ids
```

Although, upon using `echo stat | nc localhost 2181` I can see a list of kafka brokers printed on the console.

I am a bit confused here, as to how my kafka cluster is operational even though queries directed to my zookeeper cluster fail & the fact that I could not list the active kafka brokers using the `zkCli` utility.

Any insights on this are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Check the value of Zookeeper chroot path. If it is set, then the following command should be  used:

```
./zkCli.sh -server localhost:2181/zookeeper_chroot_path
ls /brokers/ids
```

There should be no space between localhost:2181 and zookeeper_chroot_path

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises often because of extra-spaces in the command line when using a zookeeper command-line handler. Just be noteful of the same.